# @JsonIgnore is not working

Tags: java, json, maven, jackson, jersey

For some reason the annotation @JsonIgnore does not work in my project.
I already read on some answers that this can be caused by using different incompatible Jackson versions (org.codehaus vs. com.fasterxml), but I am getting my jackson library only through one dependency (afaik), so that should not be the problem.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", schema = "klk")
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "token", unique = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String token;
```

Pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>  
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.eclipsesource.jaxrs/jersey-all-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.eclipsesource.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-moxy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

The output:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "password": "password",
    "token": "token
}
```

Does someone have an idea why the annotations are not working in my example?

Comment: You need to annotated the getters, not the private fields.

Comment: What is the package of the `@JsonIgnore` annotation you are using?

Comment: @shmosel That does not work either.

Comment: @acdcjunior com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Try adding the annotation to both the field and the getter.

Comment: Well, it just seems you're not using Jackson at all, but moxy. https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.

Comment: @JBNizet Removing moxy did the trick. Thank you very much! Write an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, you got the solution, but for future reference, I'm writing this answer.

As @JB Nizet pointed in his comment, you aren't using Jackson instead MOXy. And, as per **[Jersey Documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json)**

> The modules listed below provide support for JSON representations by
>   integrating the **individual JSON frameworks into Jersey**. At present,
>   Jersey integrates with the following modules to provide JSON support:
>
> - MOXy
> - Java API for JSON Processing (JSON-P)
> - Jackson
> - Jettison

So, you need to remove MOXy library to resolve this issue.